# Laravel 5 make:controller creating controller in app folder instead of controller folder

Tags: laravel, makefile, git-bash, laravel-5

I'm learning how to use Laravel 5 and I've ran into a problem where my controllers are being created in the root of the "app" folder instead of the "controller" folder. I have no idea why this is happening as I've re installed and checked 10 times.

I'm in gitbash on windows 8.1..

So I go

```
john@John ~/desktop/code/my-first-app
$ php artisan make:controller PagesController
```

and then I get

> Controller created successfully

Only it's being created in the root of `app` and nothing in the Controllers folder. What am I missing? I also see others having the same problem in comments under video on [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/4).

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please look at it

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In Laravel 5, it is not required to specify the path. By default, it will generate the controller in the directory.

So, the controller can be created like this:

```
php artisan make:controller controllerName
```

However, if you would like to create it in a custom directory then refer to the line below:

```
php artisan make:controller pathName/controllerName
```

Comment: Just tried Vijay's suggestion and it created pathNamecontrollerName. However I had success with php artisan make:controller pathName\\controllerName.

Comment: You can also  reverse the slash so it would be `php artisan make:controller pathName/controllerName`

Comment: yeah downvote because the 'custom directory' advice is clearly wrong - and has been wrong for over 2 years. To create a controller within a custom directory you need`php artisan make:controller DirectoryName/ControllerName`

Comment: @Vijay what if i had a few laravel apps.. how do I create the controller within specific app ?

Answer (score 10):

The controller can be created into specific path as followed:

```
php artisan make:controller controllerName
```

However, if you would like to create it in a custom directory then refer to the line below:

below will create on root path (outside app directory)

```
php artisan make:controller App\\../pathName/controllerName
```

If want inside app directory then it should be

```
php artisan make:controller App\\pathName/controllerName
```

Tested on Laravel 6.x

Comment: confirmed with laravel 7 - but namespaces and class names are broken, because path is not always the same like namespace....

Comment: For the namespace not be broken just do `php artisan make:controller App\pathName/controllerName`

Answer (score 2):

After trying `php artisan make:controller Directory\PageController`, Laravel 5.1 would create a controller named DirectoryPage Controller in my app directory. The solution for me was to escape the backslash with another backslash so the following worked for me:

```
php artisan make:controller Directory\\\\PageController
```

Laravel created a Pagecontroller in the `app/Directory`. Just thought I would share with everyone.

Answer (score 1):

php artisan make:controller -r controllerName

Try it with -r option it will create controller with boiler plate (All the basic function like: - public function index(){}, public function store(Request $request){}, and so on......
for better understanding you can also visit: - https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a bug in creating controllers.

I've checked it a minute ago using Laravel 5 I've installed about week or two and it was working fine. But when I installed fresh Laravel 5 now controllers are created in `app/` folder and not in `app/Http/Controllers`.

But it's also possible that developers changed their mind where controllers will be stored (Laravel 5 is still in development).

At the moment nobody knows that, you could also look at [Laracast discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/artisan-not-posting-files-in-the-right-folder?page=1) about this issue.

What is also strange you cannot manually add path to this command.

In Laravel 4 you can do:

```
php artisan controller:make --path="app/Controllers" PagesController
```

but in Laravel5 for `controller:make` you have less options comparing to Laravel 4, they are:

```
Options:
 --plain               Generate an empty controller class.
 --help (-h)           Display this help message.
 --quiet (-q)          Do not output any message.
 --verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
 --version (-V)        Display this application version.
 --ansi                Force ANSI output.
 --no-ansi             Disable ANSI output.
 --no-interaction (-n) Do not ask any interactive question.
 --env                 The environment the command should run under.
```

so you cannot put here custom path or don't generate some methods as you can in Laravel 4.

**EDIT**

It seems it is working again as it should in the newest Laravel 5 commit. So you should either create new Laravel 5 project or run:

```
composer update
```

to update project.

However you will probably get some errors as for example:

> {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class
>   'Illuminate\Routing\FilterServiceProvider' not found","file":

to remove those errors:

in file `app/Providers/FilterServiceProvider.php` change

```
use Illuminate\Routing\FilterServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

into:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\FilterServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

and in file in file `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` change

```
use Illuminate\Routing\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

into:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a composer update, and it'll be back to normal.

Comment: I'm now getting an error in the FilterServiceProvider.php on line 5 when I try to make a controller or run php artisan in general.